# Programmatically accessing Kentico alternative forms properties

Tags: forms, kentico

In Kentico 7, I'm trying to perform actions based on what alternative form is being submitted.

```
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    private class ObjectEventsAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        public override void Init()
        {
            ObjectEvents.Insert.Before += My_Create_Account_Page;

        }

        private void My_Create_Account_Page(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Object is BizFormItem && e.Object != null)
            {
                BizFormItem formEntry = (BizFormItem)e.Object;

                BizFormInfo form = formEntry.BizFormInfo;

                if (form.FormName == "MyOpenAccount")
                {
                    // somehow determine which alternative form this is

                    // do stuff with the fields in that alternative form
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been up and down the documentation and found no solution. I could add a field that I would give a default value of the alt. form name, but that opens me up to editors deleting that field, and it still doesn't tell me what other fields are in the alternative form.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that alternative form name is not accessible if you use ObjectEvents approach. But the information is known by the "Online form" (BizForm) webpart. So you probably have to customize it or create a copy. Bizform control has `AlternativeFormFullName` property and you can hook on one of its events like `OnAfterSave`.

Comment: That could be useful, if we could somehow use that string to get the fields belonging to that alternative form.  At this point, I'm thinking that's not possible.

Comment: Definitely it is possible. The same control which contains the `AlternativeFullName` property also has the `Fields` property which (once bizform is loaded) contains fields of a form/alternative form.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that gives the fields of the form, but doesn't let me see which fields are used in the alternative form, which was my (not very well described) goal. Thanks, though.

Comment: I tested it on version 8 and the `Fields` property contained only the fields visible in alternative form.